# How do i change visual studio 2019 to c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My visual studio is showing my code like this:

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub showButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles showButton.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub clearButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clearButton.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub backgroundButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles backgroundButton.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub closeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles closeButton.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

I have no idea what is that and i just want plain c#. The MS tutorial says "Use the programming language control at the top right of this page to view either the C# code snippet or the Visual Basic code snippet." But i have no idea where is that and can't find anything online...

Comment: Did you open/create a Visual Basic (VB) project by mistake?

Comment: What have you done to get where you are at? What exactly are you doing in VisualStudio?

Comment: _"Use the programming language control at the `top right of this page` to view either the `C#` code snippet or the Visual Basic code snippet." But i have no idea where is that"_ - it is referring to the web page that you were reading where you copied the code from.  _"this page"_ is pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was a little confusing, but here's what they're looking for. On your page, the code is available in C# or Visual Basic (VB). There's a button to switch between them at the top of the page, as shown in the image below.

[image: Page example]

Also, you might have accidentally created a VB project in Visual Studio instead of C#!